# toplink DB webservices Provider

Tags: web-services, oracle, jdeveloper, toplink

i'm trying to develop a jax-ws webservice based on a pl/sql package using the toplink DB WS Provider, the problem is that my procedure returns a table array and the return message is not what i was expecting.

the wsdl generated is the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-   ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Oracle JAX-WS 2.1.5. --><wsdl:definitions xmlns:ns1="http://clientwstop/testeWS" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://clientwstop/testeWSService" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" name="testeWSService" targetNamespace="http://clientwstop/testeWSService">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema xmlns:tns="http://clientwstop/testeWSService" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://clientwstop/testeWSService" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:7101/clientWStop-clientWStop-context-root/testeWS?xsd=1" namespace="http://clientwstop/testeWS"/>
<xsd:complexType name="extconResponseType">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="result">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:any/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="extconRequestType">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="ENT_COD" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="extcon" type="tns:extconRequestType"/>
<xsd:element name="extconResponse" type="tns:extconResponseType"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="extconRequest">
<wsdl:part name="extconRequest" element="tns:extcon"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="extconResponse">
<wsdl:part name="extconResponse" element="tns:extconResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="testeWSService_Interface">
<wsdl:operation name="extcon">
<wsdl:input message="tns:extconRequest"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:extconResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="testeWSService_SOAP_HTTP" type="tns:testeWSService_Interface">
<soap12:binding style="document"     transport="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/"/>
<wsdl:operation name="extcon">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://clientwstop/testeWSService:extcon"     soapActionRequired="false"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="testeWSService">
<wsdl:port name="testeWSServicePort" binding="tns:testeWSService_SOAP_HTTP">
<soap12:address location="http://localhost:7101/clientWStop-clientWStop-context-    root/testeWS"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

and the result is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<env:Body>
<srvc:extconResponse xmlns:srvc="http://clientwstop/testeWSService">
<srvc:result>
<simple-xml-format>
<simple-xml>
<result>weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Struct_oracle_sql_STRUCT@11</result>
</simple-xml>
</simple-xml-format>
</srvc:result>
</srvc:extconResponse>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Does any one tried to develop pl/sql webservices like this? what i'm doing wrong?

regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing. Here is the [best solution](http://biemond.blogspot.com/2009/01/create-plsql-webservice-in-jdeveloper.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20Java/OracleSoaBlog%20%28Java%20/%20Oracle%20SOA%20blog%29) I have found so far, and another is found [here](http://technology.amis.nl/2008/07/05/publishing-java-based-webservices-using-jax-ws-in-jdeveloper-11g/)